# PHP. Declaration function at server level

Tags: php, function

Is there a way for create function at server level scope?

For example, i've func:

```
function vd($dump){
   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($dump);
   echo "</pre>";
   exit;
}
```

I want to use it in all my project at server without include file with this function.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way if you have access to the .ini file that your server's PHP is using. It's a directive called [auto_prepend_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file), and it lets you specify a file which is essentially "included" in every page load, before the actual script runs.

It is somewhat common to see logging/tracking used with this, and your function could be declared here as well.

Comment: Looking for your ini file? If you are on 'nix, try >php -i |grep "Loaded Config"

Comment: oh, sorry for my English,
i was looking for this setting name, not ini file :)
anyway thanks